# Is any way to make this VBA code to find next same value if there are more than one?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am a beginner on vba, sarching and reading different things about vba I have created a piece of code but doesn't work how I want to. If I search for a specific value the code find it and show on specific textboxes a specific value, but if there are more than one same values (in searching column) I want to make the code go to next one until find every same value, what my actual code doesn't do. Any help on improving this code or any other code that does it I appreciate.

Here is my code,

```
Private Sub Search_Click()

Dim a As String
Dim b As Double
Dim k As Range

On Error GoTo dontexist:

If Me.TextBox20.Value = "" Or Me.TextBox20.Value = "Number of invoice" Then

    Me.Label29.Caption = "Number of invoice"

    b = Me.TextBox24.Value

    Set k = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E:E")

    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(b, k, 0)

    Me.TextBox21.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2).Value
    Me.TextBox22.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 8).Value
    Me.TextBox23.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 4).Value
    Exit Sub

Else

    Me.Label29.Caption = "Sum of invoice"

    a = Me.TextBox20.Value

    Set k = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H:H")

    r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(a, k, 0)

    Me.TextBox21.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2).Value
    Me.TextBox22.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 5).Value
    Me.TextBox23.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 4).Value
Exit Sub

End If

dontexist:

    MsgBox "This record dosn't exist!", vbInformation, "Info!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just check the value of `r` after the match to see if it is equal to `Nothing` ? (which would mean nothing was found)

Comment: Hey braX, I have tried some options but couldn't find the working one, thank you for your sudgestion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label to your form to hold the last found row and start the search from there. I have used label30.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Search_Click()

    Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range, sColumn As String
    Dim sValue As String, iCount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' label to hold row to start search at
    If Label30 = "" Then Label30 = "1"

    If Len(TextBox24) > 0 Then
        ' search on number
        sValue = TextBox24
        sColumn = "E"
        Label29 = "Number of invoice"
             
    ElseIf Len(TextBox20) > 0 Then
        ' search on total
        sValue = TextBox20
        sColumn = "H"
        Label29 = "Sum of invoice"
        
    Else
        MsgBox "No search values entered", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' count number of matches
    Set rngSearch = ws.Cells(1, sColumn).EntireColumn
    iCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSearch, sValue)
    
    If iCount > 0 Then
    
      ' continue search from last position
      Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(sValue, _
      After:= ws.Range(sColumn & Label30), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole)
      
      If rngFound Is Nothing Then
         ' not found
         Label30 = ""
         MsgBox "No more records found"
      Else
         ' is row new
         If rngFound.Row > Label30 Then
             'MsgBox rngFound.Row
             
             ' copy into text boxes
             With rngFound.EntireRow
                 If sColumn = "E" Then
                     TextBox21 = .Cells(1, 2)
                     TextBox22 = .Cells(1, 8)
                     TextBox23 = .Cells(1, 4)
                 Else
                     TextBox21 = .Cells(1, 2)
                     TextBox22 = .Cells(1, 5)
                     TextBox23 = .Cells(1, 4)
                 End If
             End With
             Label30 = rngFound.Row
             
         Else
             MsgBox "No more records found", vbExclamation
             Label30 = ""
             Exit Sub
         End If
         
      End If
    
    Else
    
       MsgBox "No records found", vbExclamation
       Label30 = ""
    
    End If
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you CDP1802, your code doesn't  have any error, but it also doesn't show any result on my textboxes except msgboxes with theyr messages. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @progstarter Try changing xlWhole to xlPart in case you have hidden spaces in your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, it did the trick, I just need to work some more on it, because if I search by Number of invoice doesn't work but it works perfectly if I search by Sum of invoice. Thank you again!